# Django says that MySQL does not allow unique CharFields to have a max_length > 255, but it does

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've got an existing mysql database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NetworkServerGroups (
        GroupID INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        GroupName VARCHAR(2048) UNIQUE NOT NULL
        )
```

After running Django's inspectdb tool, it's generated the following model (I manually modified the class name to remove the trailing 's'):

```
class Networkservergroup(models.Model):
    groupid = models.AutoField(db_column='GroupID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    groupname = models.CharField(db_column='GroupName', unique=True, max_length=2048)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'NetworkServerGroups'
```

But when I come to run the test server, it complains about the following errors:

```
control_panel.Networkservergroup.groupname: (mysql.E001) MySQL does not allow unique CharFields to have a max_length > 255.
```

But clearly, mysql does support unique CharFields with a length of > 255, because the table was created perfectly fine using the SQL statement above.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The maximum length of a unique key in MySql InnoDB table is 767 bytes, unless you have `innodb_large_prefix` set on, in which case it is 3072 bytes. See:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Since Mysql 5.7.7, `innodb_large_prefix` defaults to on. See:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix

The setting was then removed entirely in Mysql 8 and cannot be switched off.

So I'm guessing Django goes for the conservative option, as it works with Mysql 5.5:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#version-support

As @Alasdair showed in their answer, you can silence this check with the [SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS) setting:

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['mysql.E001']
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains the reason behind the issue and why I'm not facing a problem. If you could combine it with @Alasdair's answer that would complete it.

Comment: The old 255 character limit was based on 3 bytes per character, `255*3 = 765`. If the new limit is 3072, wouldn't that suggest a limit of `1024`?

Comment: The 3072 limit is in bytes. The CREATE TABLE Statement in the question does not specify a collation - so the VARCHAR value is in bytes. If the CREATE TABLE statement had specified utf 8 (by adding COLLATE utf8_general_ci) then Mysql would not have allowed a VARCHAR length higher than 1024 characters, as that is 3072 bytes.

Comment: The `innodb_large_prefix` was deprecated and removed. As of mysql8 (current version), this option itself is not available

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off the warning in your project with the [`SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS) setting:

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['mysql.E001']
```

If the 255 limit only applied to older versions of Django or in certain circumstances, then perhaps the check should be modified or removed. The django-developers mailing list would be a good place to ask about this. I'm not familiar with MySQL so I don't know the cases in which unique CharFields with length > 255 are allowed.